# TF Keras Text Processing - Classification Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, data-science

I posted a question earlier about a TensorFlow script that I wrote that wasn't working properly.  I've narrowed down the problem, and deleted the old comment, I hope this one is easier to follow.  I'm basically trying to follow the classic example of predicting movie comments on IMDB which are either positive or negative.  I've looked at many variations of this, and my main problem is that my model is returning the same label prediction (the label being the sentiment, positive/negative).  I'm 99% sure the problem is in my model build/compile:

```
NUM_WORDS = 10000
SEQ_LEN = 512
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 300
BATCH_SIZE = 500
EPOCHS = 20

**model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(NUM_WORDS, 32, input_length = BATCH_SIZE),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')])**

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_accuracy', mode = 'max')

callbacks = [es]
history = model.fit(train_seqs, train_df['adq'].values,
                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs = EPOCHS,
                    validation_split = 0.2,
                    callbacks = callbacks)

model.evaluate(test_seqs, test_df['adq'].values)


model.save('model.ps1')
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

del model
del tokenizer


loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.ps1')

with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    loaded_tokenizer = pickle.load(f)

def prepare_predict_data(tokenizer, comments):
    seqs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(comments)
    seqs = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(seqs, maxlen = SEQ_LEN, padding = 'post')
    return seqs
```

My text preprocessing cleanup, tokenization, and padding are all working, and I have 38000 or so comments in my training set, each with an sequence length of 512, again the padding looks good.  Can you please let me know where i'm going wrong?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but in general, I think with 38K training examples it is better to use a pretrained embedding (e.g. GloVe) rather than training your own 32-d embedding.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is not the early stopping, what's the result of `len(history.history['accuracy'])`?

Comment: @fmarm i just ran it without the bottom pickle section and model save.  len(history.history['accuracy']) comes back as 3.  here's the actual output from the model summary:

Comment: Epoch 1/20
30880/30880 [==============================] - 4s 141us/sample - loss: 0.6217 - accuracy: 0.6479 - val_loss: 0.3910 - val_accuracy: 0.8377
Epoch 2/20
30880/30880 [==============================] - 4s 115us/sample - loss: 0.2704 - accuracy: 0.8902 - val_loss: 0.2830 - val_accuracy: 0.8835
Epoch 3/20
30880/30880 [==============================] - 4s 115us/sample - loss: 0.1562 - accuracy: 0.9446 - val_loss: 0.2973 - val_accuracy: 0.8834
4769/4769 [==============================] - 0s 84us/sample - loss: 0.2824 - accuracy: 0.8926
3

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(NUM_WORDS, 100, input_length = SEQ_LEN),
tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response!  i tried running  this, and i intially got an error indicating that the expected embedding_input shape was 512, but that the array was 256, which came back on the model fit.so i changed by batch size value to 256 and i'm still getting the same value.  I'm wondering if my arguments for the batch size and input length etc, are causing the problem...

Comment: https://austingwalters.com/fasttext-for-sentence-classification/